# How to disable escaping HTML entities in JSON for API, but leave it enabled for views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, xss, activesupport

`config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json` is enabled by deafult in Rails (v4, v5) and it protects from some XSS attacks by encoding HTML entities `<`, `>`, `&` and it's great for views (html)

But I think this encoding is redundant in API responses:

```
render status: :ok, json: { link: 'https://example.com?p1=v1&p2=v2' }
```

I expect to get:

```
{ link: 'https://example.com?p1=v1&p2=v2' }
```

instead of

```
{ link: 'https://example.com?p1=v1\u0026p2=v2' }
```

How to disable escaping HTML entities in JSON for API, but leave it enabled for views?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
render json: JSON.generate({ link: 'https://example.com?p1=v1&p2=v2' })
```

output:

```
{"link":"https://example.com?p1=v1&p2=v2"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your object in `as_json` like so:

```
render status: :ok, json: { link: 'https://example.com?p1=v1&p2=v2' }.as_json
```

[More info on `as_json`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json)

Comment: It does not work: `ApplicationController.render status: :ok, json: { link: 'https://example.com?p1=v1&p2=v2' }.as_json` returns `"{\"link\":\"https://example.com?p1=v1\\u0026p2=v2\"}"`